# What is the unicode for julia 1.0 Integer Div symbol

Tags: julia

On vi program, I can enter the unicode by

first enter the "insert mode" using 'i'

Then type 'CTRL-v' follow by 'u2611' to enter unicode-2611

I wish to enter the unicode character for "julia 1.0 Integer Div symbol"

But I have no idea what the unicode value for it is and when I looked at the julia 1.0 documentation, it does not tell me

https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0.0/manual/mathematical-operations/

What is the unicode for julia 1.0 Integer Div symbol?

Comment: Using my favorite search engine I found the symbol to be U+00F7 using the search terms “Unicode divide”

Comment: Maybe this is the Julia Doc link you are looking for?  [Unicode Input](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0.0/manual/unicode-input/)

Comment: I think i found it. Press CTRL-COMMAND-SPACE then type "u+00f7" then press DOWNARROW then press ENTER. Of course this only works on the OSX (aka the Mac). This would work on all text editors on the Mac

Comment: Have you considered the julia-vim plugin? Then you can type `\div<tab>` to insert the div unicode symbol. https://github.com/JuliaEditorSupport/julia-vim#latex-to-unicode-substitutions

Answer (score 7):

You can find all unicode that could be entered by tab completion. For you question,

```
U+000F7 ÷   \div    Division Sign
```

In julia repl, type `\div` then `Tab` to complete this.

Comment: I forget to leave link... https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/unicode-input/

Comment: Link broken. Try this: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/unicode-input/